# Calculate Total Working Days of month

Tags: sql-server

I have this table where I am specifying Holidays in week. I want to calculate total working days between 2 specific dates using these fields.

```
CREATE TABLE [tbl_Shift](
[OffDay1] [nvarchar](25) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_tbl_Shift_OffDay1]  DEFAULT (N'Sunday'),
[IsAlternateOffDay2] [bit] NULL,
[OffDay2] [nvarchar](25) NULL
)

INSERT INTO [tbl_Shift] VALUES ('Sunday', 'True', 'Saturday')
```

I have this query written but I am not able to get correct days. It should give 23 days as there are 2 holidays in each week and 31 days in total but I'm getting 26 days.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME
SET @StartDate = '2018/05/01'
SET @EndDate = '2018/05/31'


SELECT
   (DATEDIFF(dd, @StartDate, @EndDate+1)) -(DATEDIFF(wk, @StartDate, @EndDate))
   -(CASE WHEN IsAlternateOffday2 = 1 THEN 1 END) FROM HRM.tbl_Shift
```

Comment: *"This query"*? I don't see a query in your question. :)

Comment: Whoa, Sorry my bad. Let me edit. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: @Larnu Please check now. hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will give 23:

```
SELECT
    (DATEDIFF(dd, @StartDate, @EndDate+1)) -(DATEDIFF(wk, @StartDate, @EndDate))
    -ISNULL((CASE WHEN IsAlternateOffday2 = 1 THEN (DATEDIFF(wk, @StartDate, @EndDate)) END), 0) 
FROM HRM.tbl_Shift
```

Comment: I have updated the value of IsAlternateOffday2 to NULL and now I am getting NULL as total Count.

Comment: NULL Should be Considered as False,  right.? and the output should 27 or 26.?

Comment: Output should be 27 and 23 in case Saturday is offday. I have made the update and this works for me.

Answer (score 1):

This subtracts 2 days for every weekend. Check your server config if Sunday is first or last day of the week. This can throw things off by a weekend.

```
SELECT DATEPART(WEEKDAY,'20180506') --Checks if Sunday is Day 1 or Day 7

DECLARE @start DATETIME = '20180501'
DECLARE @end DATETIME = '20180531'

SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,@start,@end+1) - (DATEDIFF(WEEK,@start,@end+1)*2)
```

UPDATE:

Use COALESCE to replace NULLS with an alternative value.

```
DECLARE @offdate DATETIME = NULL

SELECT COALESCE(@offdate,GETDATE())
```

Comment: But what If OffDay2 is NULL ?

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE ='2018-05-01',
        @EndDate DATE ='2018-05-31'
;WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT DATEADD(DD,Number-1,@StartDate) MOnthDates,
       DATENAME(DW,DATEADD(DD,Number-1,@StartDate)) As DayNAmes,
       CASE WHEN DATENAME(DW,DATEADD(DD,Number-1,@StartDate)) IN ('Saturday','Sunday') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END WeekDays
FROM master.dbo.spt_values
WHERE [Type]='P'
AND Number Between 1 AND 10000
)
SELECT COUNT(WeekDays)  AS WeekDaysCount
FROM CTE
WHERE WeekDays<>0
AND MOnthDates Between @StartDate AND DATEADD(DAY,1,@EndDate)
```

Result

```
WeekDaysCount
-------------
23
```

Demo:http://rextester.com/TOLYT35075

Comment: this doesn't calculate correctly. Try from '2018-03-30' to '2018-06-15'

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Thanks For ur correction,just i updated the code

Answer (score 0):

This was what I created after reviewing the answers. I needed the number of days per month for several months. The below will provide that, and insert it into the `#MonthDayCount` table. Note: I named a field `Month`, even though that is a SQL Server defined term; you can change it if needed.

You must enter the first day of the month and the last for it to count the first and last month correctly. If you entered `1/2/2022`, it would result in January being short one day.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '1/01/2021'--The start of the first month the number of days are needed for.
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = '1/31/2021'--The end of the first month the number of days are needed for.
DECLARE @FinalDate DATE = '12/31/2022'--This is the last month that will be inserted. Includes this month.

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MonthDayCount', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #MonthDayCount; 
CREATE TABLE #MonthDayCount
                            (
                                [Month]             VARCHAR(MAX),
                                [# of WeekDays]     INT,
                                [EOM]               DATE
                            )


WHILE           @StartDate <= @FinalDate
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO     
    #MonthDayCount
                    VALUES  (
                                DATENAME(m,@StartDate),
                                (
                                    DATEDIFF(dd, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1)
                                    -(DATEDIFF(wk, @StartDate, @EndDate) * 2)
                                    -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @StartDate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                                    -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @EndDate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                                ),
                                @EndDate
                            )


  SET @StartDate = DATEADD(m,1,@StartDate)
  SET @EndDate = EOMONTH(@EndDate,1)
 


END
```

Comment: Sorry about the formatting. My first answer here.

Comment: It's no problem. I've edited your answer to improve the formatting. But please do review the [edit] so that you can format future answers on your own. Thank you for your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

**MS SQL Server query to find count of all the working days (non Saturdays and Sundays) in current month.
Works in SQL Server, Azure Synapse Analytics**

Note:
Change the getdate() as per your need.

```
SELECT Day(Eomonth(Getdate())) - ( Datediff(d, Dateadd(d, Datediff(d, -1,
                                               Dateadd(month, Month(
                                               Getdate()) - 1 + (
                                   Year(Getdate()
                                   ) - 1900 )
                                   *
                                   12, 6)) / 7 * 7, -1),
                                   Dateadd(m, 1, Dateadd(
                                   month,
                                                 Month(Getdate())
                                                 - 1 +
                                                 (
                                   Year(Getdate()) - 1900 )
                                                 *
                                                 12, 6
                                                 )
                                   )) / 7 +
                                          Datediff(d, Dateadd(d, Datediff(d, -1,
                                                                 Dateadd(
                                                                 month,
                                                      Month(Getdate()) - 1 + (
                                          Year(Getdate()
                                          ) - 1900 )
                                          *
                                          12, 7)) / 7 * 7, -1), Dateadd(m, 1,
                                          Dateadd(month, Month(Getdate()) - 1 +
                                                         (
                                          Year(Getdate()) - 1900 ) *
                                                              12, 7)
                                          )) / 7 ) AS Num_Working_Days
```